# Invalid ELF image for this architecture when unning an ASP.NET Core on aarch64

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, arm64

I am trying to run an ASP.NET Core 3.0 app that is Self-Contained published for the linux-arm runtime on a docker container that has the following return when running *uname -a*:

```
Linux bf9817f9ceb3 4.15.0-153-generic #160-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 29 06:54:29 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

After some research, I understood that ASP.NET Core is able to run on arm, but if I try to run the Chat executable, it returns me the following error:

```
./Chat: Invalid ELF image for this architecture
```

Doess wnyone know what's this about?

Comment: Ok so after more research, I have found that usinf dotnet CLI, I can publish to linux-arm64. However, by doing this I get the following error: qemu: Unsupported syscall: 283
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 168
Segmentation fault (core dumped)